# How to make Django Rest Apis Async

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, async-await, python-asyncio

Following is my Django application configuration:

```
django = 2.2.11
djangorestframework = 3.9.2
Python = 3.8.2
```

I am exposing a set of Rest apis for react js frontend, which connects to Postgres using a layered architecture `views (controller) - services - data_layer`. In data layer, I fetch the data using `Connection.Cursor`, then transform the data fetched using `cursor.fetchall`.

By default the rest apis are synchronous apis, I am trying to find a way to make them Async, so that system scalability can be increased, otherwise every call will block the main thread.

I have tried the following options:

1. Using asyncio library, but I am unable to make the complete call chain Async. I generally get an error that expected return was Response / HttpResponse, but the method is returning Co-routine. I can find examples which contains running simple methods as async, but there's isn't an example of Django Rest API
2. Tried the following [link](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-asynchronous-web-requests-in-parallel-with-python-3-5-without-aiohttp-264dc0f8546), which use the Threadpool executor to segregate every call on a thread in the controller itself, though the challenge is where to make the Asyncio call in the Main method as shown in the link, since these APIs are externally invoked.
3. Can aiohttp help, not sure, but if anyone has an example otherwise I have to resort to service broker design using an intermediary like Redis which in my view is unrequired complexity.

Any help / link on the topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? 
I would like to make a bunch of external API requests but would prefer not to offload it to celery. Getting the same error (that it received a couroutine instead of Response)

Comment: @Thorvald you may review the following, 

https://pypi.org/project/asgiref/

This can help making all the non controller methods Async, another option remains use the Threadpool for non async IO calls

Answer (score 0):

If your Django application is only reading and writing to a database then going async is unlikely to provide any speedup, because Django's ORM is not async (up to version 4.1 at time of writing).  All your async views/controllers will end up blocking on the non-async database queries.

If you are making other web service (HTTP) calls in your views/controllers then you could make them async and use aiohttp or httpx, however DRF does not (yet) support async views, so something's gotta give.  Either use Django async without DRF, or keep DRF and stay sync.

Good discussion about async in DRF is at https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/discussions/7774